# ¿Como mostrar hora actual en java?

Tags: java

```
long tMinTotal = System.currentTimeMillis() / (60 * 1000);
int tMinCurrent = (int) (tMinTotal % (24 * 60));
hours = tMinCurrent / 60;
minutes = tMinCurrent % 60;
```

Se que es así como se hace pero no entiendo que hace la segunda linea. 
Gracias.

Answer (score 9):

Se puede obtener de varias formas,

usando la clase [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) :

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
 Date date = new Date();
  System.out.println("Hora actual: " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

usando la clase [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
LocalDateTime locaDate = LocalDateTime.now();
int hours  = locaDate.getHour();
int minutes = locaDate.getMinute();
int seconds = locaDate.getSecond();
System.out.println("Hora actual : " + hours  + ":"+ minutes +":"+seconds);
```

para ambas opciones, se obtiene el formato `HH:mm:ss` , ejemplo de salida:

```
Hora actual: 10:28:29
```

#### Obtener hora actual a partir de System.currentTimeMillis() :

En tu caso veo que la tratas de obtener a partir de el valor de `System.currentTimeMillis()` por lo tanto tienes dos opciones para obtener la hora actual `UTC`:

1) Opción usando la clase `TimeUnit` :

```
     long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("Hora actual: " + String.format("%d min, %d sec",
             TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
             TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
                     TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
     ));
```

2) Esta opción es similar a la que tratas de realizar:

```
 long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
 int hours   = (int) ((millis / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
 int minutes = (int) ((millis / (1000*60)) % 60);
 int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000) % 60 ;

 System.out.println("Hora actual : " + hours + ":"+ minutes+":"+seconds);
```

Answer (score 4):

Es más simple si los obtienes a traves del `LocalDateTime`

```
LocalDateTime ahora= LocalDateTime.now();
    int año = ahora.getYear();
    int mes = ahora.getMonthValue();
    int dia = ahora.getDayOfMonth();
    int hora = ahora.getHour();
    int minutos = ahora.getMinute();
    int segundos = ahora.getSecond();
```

En tu caso lo que haces es calcular la hora y minutos a través de los milisegundos actuales.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias formas de mostrar la hora actual. Te dejo algunas formas.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); /2016/11/16 12:08:43

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal)); //2016/11/16 12:08:43
```

Answer (score 2):

Acá te comenté cada linea.

```
//Obtengo los minutos "totales" de la fecha (le saco los milisegundos)
long tMinTotal = System.currentTimeMillis() / (60 * 1000);
//Obtengo el resto al dividir los minutos por los días, el cual corresponde a "todos" los minutos del día
//(o sea, sin son las 1:15, esta variable va a valor 75)
int tMinCurrent = (int) (tMinTotal % (24 * 60));
//Obtengo las horas que hay en los minutos
hours = tMinCurrent / 60;
//Obtengo el resto al dividir los minutos por las horas, lo que nos da los minutos
minutes = tMinCurrent % 60;
```

Ojalá se entienda.

¡Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar la clase [Calendar](http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:Calendar).

De esta manera, puedes obtener rápidamente la fecha y hora.

Para obtener la hora solo debes escribir:

```
Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
int hora, minutos, segundos;
hora = calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
segundos = calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND);
System.out.println(hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos);
```